# Get HWID (processorID, MotherboardSerialNumber)

Tags: vb.net

I am working on a project, and my problem, when I try to get the motherboard serial number its totally empty.

```
Dim HWID As String = String.Empty
Dim mcl As New ManagementClass("win32_processor")
Dim MOBC As ManagementObjectCollection = mcl.GetInstances()

For Each mob As ManagementObject In MOBC
    If HWID = "" Then
        HWID = mob.Properties("processorID").Value.ToString()
        Exit For
    End If

Next
Dim mboardstr As String = Nothing
 Dim mbs As ManagementObjectSearcher = New ManagementObjectSearcher("Select * From Win32_BaseBoard")
For Each mo As ManagementObject In mbs.Get
    mboardstr = mboardstr + mo("SerialNumber").ToString
Next
MsgBox(mboardstr)
```

HWID - processorid is okey, but I really want the motherboard serial too, because after that I put it into one string and post it to the remote host.

Why I dont have "serialnumber"? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not all data is available on all systems.  In this case, there might be other data ahead of the text you are looking for which prevents the string from being fetched.  WMI is pretty slow, so you can speed it up by just querying for what you are after (vs `SELECT *`).

Some of those things should be disposed of to release resources and you should check some of the things to make sure they are not null before using them:

```
Dim mboardstr As String = ""
Dim query As String = "Select SerialNumber From Win32_BaseBoard"

Using mbs As ManagementObjectSearcher = New ManagementObjectSearcher(query)
    For Each mo As ManagementObject In mbs.Get
        For Each pd As PropertyData In mo.Properties
            ' should be only one
            If pd.Name = "SerialNumber" Then
                ' value is object, test for Nothing
                If pd.Value IsNot Nothing Then
                    mboardstr = pd.Value.ToString
                End If
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Using
```

You could also set a breakpoint, and examine `pd.Value` to see if there are leading nuls or other unprintable control characters (quite common).  What you are after might be "behind" them.

Comment: And have you got any idea how to make a special ID for each pc?
Because If I use only processorid for HWID some pc can have the same not? After the program started, I send the hwid to a remove php (post method) and check its in the database, if yes, I give back its banned or not, if not program start to run. if banned its close.. :) Thats why its important for me, to give special ID for each pc.

Comment: Use a hardware hash - several pieces of data glued together then hashed.  What you describe may get you in trouble with privacy laws - storing other people's hardware IDs.

Comment: Yep thats what I want several pieces of data in one string and after make a hash. But I dont have idea to get any data.. I mean I get the processorid, I cannot get the motherboard serial because its give back nothink.. What can I use for it? It must be the same on every program start, thats why I try to make it with hwid.

Comment: First, the MB data might be there - do what I suggested and look at it under debug.  Second, SO doesnt do question-chaining.  If you have a new question, ask it.  There are plenty of posts here on hashing so research first

Comment: with a hash it doesnt have to be the same "for every program" - not sure that that means - it *does* need to be the same each time it runs on a given machine

Comment: I have checked with breakpoints and its nothing in serial number. Okey, thanks I will ask in a new one if I have problem with it. I just dont know how to search it, what is the good keyw. to find my answer, because I am totally newbie in programming, but I need to do it in vb.net, thats why I asked. Thanks for the answeres and for the short code.

Comment: And when the program start I need to make this hash each time, send to the serverside, and the serverside is store it in the sql, so I select it if its exist and I give back its banned or not, if not exist I put it into the db. Have nice day.

Comment: to test, set a breakpoint, then get the contents get the string then `Dim temp = mboardstr.ToCharArray()` hold the mouse over temp and you can expand it to look at each character