# Make pc specific hash in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, hash

I want to make a program, which generate the same string each time, and it must be different on any each pc. So like HWID.  After I have the string I send it into a php file on a remote host, the php handle it, and store it in the database.

On the first run it will make a new row in the table, but after 2nd run, it will select the row where the POST-ed hash = the hash in the table, and it has banned - not banned function. So if I give back 0 the pc is not banned, so program start to run, if I give back 1 the program close.

This is all made, my problem is, I generate hwid from processorid, and send it to the php. the processorid can be the same on different computers sometimes. So if I give fake ban, the users will be angry for me...

The question is:
How to generate a hash, which will be always the same on the pc which run the application, but different on each pc?

I know I can make it if I store a special id on the pc for example in the registry, but if somebody reinstall the pc, he can use again the service. If I generate hwid, it will takes him more time to find out how to access again to the service.

Comment: how is this php related? Is there a php-specific aspect to it?

Comment: I post the data to an url/handle.php and if isset $_POST['hwdata'] I make the things, if not its just a blank page.

Comment: Since you can now upvote answers, please click the up arraow next to the asnwer if it helped

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I dont think this really has anything to do with PHP, but entirely about the client side steps.

To do what it sounds like you want, you want to use a hardware signature made up of several things so that if one or two are unavailable, the result is still valid. This will use a form of the WMI polling procedure from the answer on your [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34980373/get-hwid-processorid-motherboardserialnumber):

```vb
Private Shared Function GetHardwareItemInfo(item As String, wmiclass As String) As String
    Dim data As String = ""
    Dim query As String = String.Format("Select {0} From {1}", item, wmiclass)
    Using mbs As ManagementObjectSearcher = New ManagementObjectSearcher(query)
        For Each mo As ManagementObject In mbs.Get
            For Each pd As PropertyData In mo.Properties
                ' should be only one
                If String.Compare(pd.Name, item, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) = 0 Then
                    ' value is object, test for Nothing
                    If pd.Value IsNot Nothing Then
                        data = pd.Value.ToString
                    End If
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next
        Next
    End Using

    Return data
End Function
```

This allows you to poll for different items in different wmi classes using the same code.  Example:

```vb
' get the serialnumber item from the baseboard class:
answer = GetHardwareItemInfo("serialNumber", "Win32_BaseBoard")
```

For a hardware signature:

- Get and store the info for each item
- Combine them into one string
- Convert the string to a byte array
- Use crypto to hash the byte array
- convert the result to a base64 string

There are other ways.  For instance you could encode the result as a Hex string, but the above is what the code shows.  First, these are the namespaces you need:

```vb
Imports System.Security.Cryptography
Imports System.Management
Imports System.Text
```

Then the procedure to get the stuff using the `GetHardwareItemInfo` method above:

```vb
' place to store bits of data
Dim HWStuff As New List(Of String)
Dim answer As String

' get and store some info
answer = GetHardwareItemInfo("serialNumber", "Win32_BaseBoard")
HWStuff.Add(answer)
answer = GetHardwareItemInfo("uuid", "win32_ComputerSystemProduct")
HWStuff.Add(answer)
answer = GetHardwareItemInfo("serialNumber", "Win32_OperatingSystem")
HWStuff.Add(answer)
'...etc

' glue the bits together into one string
Dim HWSig = String.Join("", HWStuff)
Dim byteHash As Byte()

' create crypto hasher
Using hasher = New SHA1Managed()
    ' convert the string to bytes
    Dim tmpBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(HWSig)
    'hash the bytes
    byteHash = hasher.ComputeHash(tmpBytes)
End Using
' encode as B64 string.
Dim HWHash = Convert.ToBase64String(byteHash)

Console.WriteLine(HWHash)
```

Result:

> MUjeLeZtbTQ3Rc8zgFquBkOwFzA=

You could glue the string together as you get answers.  But during development it helps to see the candidate info before you decide to use it or not.

Notes:

- There are many many things to choose from.  See [WMI Win32 Classes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394084(v=vs.85).aspx).
- Not everything needs to come from WMI.  the LocalMachine name might be a good one (I have no idea of the context for this) as is the Windows Activation Key.
- Other crypto hashers will produce longer hashes
- This is far from foolproof.
- Some things can be spoofed - the Win OS Serial number can be changed in the registry.  You dont really care if the values are right, just that they do not change.
- This is not copy protection.  Someone could sniff out the token(s) sent from a legitimate system(s), then patch your app to send that token only.

`if I store a special id...`

No.  Do not write anything down.  Its impossible to keep a secret from the user on their own PC.  Dont store the hash either - generate it every time.  If you write it down it is easier to copy that value to a different machine.

`I give fake ban, the users will be angry for me...`

Since it sounds like you are working from a blacklist rather than a whitelist, you dont have to worry about the hash failing.  The worst that will happen is that a system which should be denied access will get access.  If you want to further reduce the chance of a match, use `SHA512Managed`; it will produce a longer hash though.

If a user changes one of the parts you are polling, they will still get in - it is quite unlikely that the hash from 2 systems will match (one white, one black).